# Can't serialize BsonDocument to Json from MVC3 using official C# driver

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, mongodb, json.net, mongodb-.net-driver

My web client sends Json. MongoDB is practically Json. It should be easy, but I'm getting tied in knots fighting the C# driver in MVC3. It seems there's no easy way to avoid working in C# classes. I'd have thought it would be easy just to pass Json back and forth with a little filtering. Its like I'm fighting an ORM and I don't want to be.

Anyway, I've (begrudgingly) built my data model in C#, I'm using Json.Net and my serialization code looks like;

My serialization code for a JsonResult is;

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
    ...
    var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
}
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this without an object mapping. I have a controller action thus;

```
public JsonResult test() 
{
    var col = _db.GetCollection<Project>("myCollection");

    var jsText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Controllers"), "MapReducers.js"));
    string map_cashflow = new Regex(@"//function map_cashflow(.*?)//end", RegexOptions.Singleline).Match(jsText).Captures[0].ToString();
    string reduce_cashflow = new Regex(@"//function reduce_cashflow(.*?)//end", RegexOptions.Singleline).Match(jsText).Captures[0].ToString();

    var mr = col.MapReduce(map_cashflow, reduce_cashflow);
    return Json(mr, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

Now this works when I serialize cursors elsewhere (for some reason), but I now understand the above fails because it's trying to serialize the actual BsonDocument rather than the underlying data. I get an error when it tries to serialize the first field as some other type, usually trying to convert a string or a date to AsBoolean(). It's a shame the driver can't allow the doc to be serialized a little more easily.

I had similar trouble trying to use a BsonDocument to represent a dynamic piece of my object graph. I figured better that than a json string, but of course it won't serialize. I ended up using Dictionary<> which is fine.

I've also tried these with similar results;

```
return Json(mr.GetResults());
return Json(mr.GetResults()).ToArray();
```

So I've also tried the following I've seen people have success with;

```
var jsonText = mr.ToJson(); // empty
var jsonText = mr.GetResults().toJson(); // Exception: No serializer found for type System.Collections.IEnumerator.
```

All I want to do is throw back what looks almost exactly like Json already but I can't figure out how to serialize it. Is this the only way?

```
var resultsObj = mr.GetResultsAs<ResultsClass>();
```

If so, that sucks. I don't want to be building statically typed classes just to house results documents. It's ORM gone mad! I don't need to go in and out of C# objects, the driver really is more of a hindrance than a help. I think I'd rather just have the Json please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any reason why you would need to create an object model for this, unless MVC3 is imposing that requirement on you. Using BsonDocument and serializing straight to a JSON string should be fine. It's hard to wade through most of your post, but zeroing in on the result of calling MapReduce, the GetResults() method returns a value of type IEnumerable<BsonDocument>, which you should be able to easily convert to JSON. Here's a simple test:

```
IEnumerable<BsonDocument> results = new BsonDocument[] 
{
    new BsonDocument("x", 1),
    new BsonDocument("x", 2)
};
var json = results.ToJson();
```

When I run this code the json variable end up with the following content:

```
[{ "x" : 1 }, { "x" : 2 }]
```

In particular, I don't get the exception you mentioned. Can you make sure you are using a new enough version of the C# driver, and if you still get the exception post back the full stack trace?

Part of the problem might be coming from mixing and matching BsonDocument with a JSON serializer that is not part of the C# driver. Third party JSON serializers (like the Json method you are using that returns a JsonResult) typically impose their own constraints on what they can and can't serialize. So the problems you are encountering would appear to be external to the MongoDB C# driver.

Sorry, I really don't know enough about MVC3 and how it expects to converts results back to JSON to say much about that.

Comment: Thanks. I've switched to calling BsonDocument::ToJson(), but now I've  a different problem. The MongoDB.Driver serializer returns json that causes my browser to choke. I've changed JsonOutputMode and tried all four. JavaScript and Strict both send invalid json that causes chrome to choke. $data is a strange nested format and TenGen returns the same as JavaScript.

Comment: I'm using trying to use a reviver function to hook into JSON.parse() on the browser, but it's choking way before calling me. Is there any way of getting the driver to at least put the ISODate("") stuff into quotes so my client doesn't choke on the format?

Comment: In fact the $date format is no good either. It's missing the commas between array elements. Every single variant of the ToJson() method on BsonDocument seems flawed and returns invalid Json.

Comment: So in summary, it seems that BsonDomument.ToJson() will *only* produce invalid Json. Eg;         "_id": ISODate("2011-01-01T00:00:00Z"), and the browser chokes on tokenization. There are other formats, but they're very similar and the ALL miss the commas between array elements, so that's no use at all

Comment: BSON is a superset of JSON, so there will be issues when trying to convert BSON to JSON when the document contains data types that JSON doesn't support. The C# driver JsonOutputMode Strict *always* produces valid JSON, although it has to represent data types not supported in JSON using nested documents and strings. The other JsonOutputModes produce JSON strings that are only valid inside MongoDB. I've never seen the C# driver JSON serializer not put commas between array elements (the sample output above has a comma between the two array elements).

Answer (score 1):

So, I've written a one-way plugin for Json.Net that will allow me to serialize BsonDocuments using the toJson() method on the document itself. It's not ideal because I now have two different serializer stacks;

```
public class BsonDocumentConverterPlugin : Newtonsoft.Json,JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        BsonDocument bsonDoc = (BsonDocument)value;
        writer.WriteRaw(bsonDoc.ToJson());
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Serialisation back to Bson not supported in this converter");
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(BsonDocument));
    }
}
```

and in my JsonResult override;

```
        var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data, Formatting.None, 
                new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                                             Converters = new List<JsonConverter>() { new BsonDocumentConverterPlugin() }
                });
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to work for my MapReduce resultset which has multiple results as it doesn't serialise them as an array and misses the commas out resulting in the invalid json, no matter which serialization method I use. BsonDocument.ToJson() also writes invalid json for dates. Under strict it writes ISODate() and under JavaScript/TenGen it writes newDate(). Both of these cause my browser to barf.

So in the end, I've had to resort to building an object graph after all;

```
    public class MrResultsetCashflow
    {
        [MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes.BsonId]
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public FinancialItem value;
    }
```

and I go through the original MVC/json.net serialization stack;

```
        var f = mr.GetResultsAs<MrResultsetCashflow>();
        return Json(f, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Did you ever find an another solution to the problem how ToJson handles dates? I happened to encounter the exact same problem as you did, where BsonDocument.ToJson formats dates like "ISODate("2012-09-29T00:00:00Z")" which JSON.NET isn't able to handle.

Comment: Using JSON.Net serialization I don't have the problem as it handles dates correctly. I don't know why BsonDocumnet.ToJson() is so busted. I previously used a JS library on the client to process the MongoDB driver output based on this http://blog.activa.be/index.php/2010/03/handling-dates-in-json-responses-with-jquery-1-4-the-easy-way/

Comment: Here's a fork of the official driver which allows you to output the dates in ISO-8601 format: https://nuget.org/packages/MongoDBISODatesDriver.

Usage:             
JsonWriterSettings.Defaults.UseIso8601DateFormat = true;
var json = bsondoc.ToJson();

Output: 
"date" : 2012-09-29T00:00:00

Comment: Smashing! I hope that gets merged into the official driver.